# Read log file and save into smaller files of 5MB each

Tags: java

I have a large log file (dozens of MB) and I need to create smaller logs, of 3MB each.

I have the code to create the first log file of 3MB but I'm not able to move forward and create the next log file of 3MB.

Here's my code that creates the first smaller log of 3MB.

```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(sourceFile))

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bytesLeft = 3 * 1024 * 1024; 

  int i=0;                                
      
  // reads 3MB bytes at a time, if end of the file, returns -1
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\output"+i+".log");
    
  try {
      while (bytesLeft > 0) {
        int read = fis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(bytesLeft, buffer.length));
        if (read == -1) {
          throw new EOFException("Unexpected end of data");
        }
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        bytesLeft -= read;
        i++;
      }
  } finally {
      fos.close(); 
   }
```

This works great. However, I'm not being able to move forward and create the next log after reading the first 3MB from the sourceFile.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where does `i` come from in this line: `new FileOutputStream("D:\\output"+i+".log");`? Is the code you posted in a loop, or a separate method?

Comment: The i is used to generate a unique log file for each 3MB from the original log file.

Comment: I understand that is your intent, but where do you initialize it? Can you show a few more lines of code around what you posted?

Comment: Just above the While. 
  int i=0;

There is no other method or loop, I'm on the case where the log file is larger than 3MB.

Comment: I am guessing there is another `while` above the code you actually posted. The error may be in the condition of that while, but since you did not post it, there is no way to tell.

Comment: I've removed that loop, so you can consider there is no other while.

Comment: This code will split lines across chunks.  You probably don’t want that.

Comment: @Lev M. It seems that I cannot figure out how to move forward in the big log file after reading the first 5MB. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only loop over the `bytesLeft` and don't continue reading the available data once the first 3MB are read.

Here is a possible solution with some comments:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  final int chunkSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024; // 3MB
  final String sourceFile = "D:/path/to/large/file";
  read(sourceFile, chunkSize);
}

private static void read(String sourceFile, int chunkSize) throws Exception {

  final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

  // use try-with-resource to ensure the input stream is closed
  try (final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(sourceFile))) {
    int read = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // continue to read until there is no data available anymore
    do {
      // reset bytesLeft at the start of every iteration
      int bytesLeft = chunkSize; 
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      try {
        // write to the same output file as long as the desired chunk size
        // is not reached and there is data
        while (bytesLeft > 0 && (read = fis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(bytesLeft, buffer.length))) > 0) {
          // only open a new output file once for every iteration and only
          // if there was data read
          if (bytesLeft == chunkSize) {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/output-" + i + ".txt");
          }
          fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
          bytesLeft -= read;
        }
      } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
          fos.close();
        }
      }
      i++;
    } while (read > 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing to the same file the whole time. Move the following line inside the `while-loop`:
`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\output"+i+".log");`

like in the following example

```
try {
    while (bytesLeft > 0) {
        // try putting this line inside the while loop.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\output"+i+".log");
        int read = fis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(bytesLeft, buffer.length));
        if (read == -1)
            throw new EOFException("Unexpected end of data");
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        bytesLeft -= read;
        i++;
    }
} finally {
    fos.close(); 
}
```

Comment: This is probably not what OP wanted - `bytesLeft` is initialized to 3MB, which is the desired output size, but your code treats it like the size of the input file. This is why I asked the OP where the `i` comes from - we need to know what is around the posted code to properly answer this (or just write new code from scratch based on the verbal description)

Comment: The i is used to save the next 3MB into a new file "D:\\output"+i+".log", just to generate a new name for the log file.

Comment: It seems that I cannot figure out how to move forward in the big log file after reading the first 5MB. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @J.Tribbiani the `i` is being changed inside the `while-loop`. The value of `fos` is just an output stream, pointing initially at `D://output0.log` (assuming that `i` is initialised with 0)